# How to make a moving sprite fall with physics in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I have a moving object that spawns object2 thats attached by a sliding joint

When i press the button , the joint is removed and the object2 falls down with gravity

this works, but only falls down on the x axis without retaining its y axis speed.

How can i make Object2 fall down in a more horizontal way like in real life

[Scene Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfied.gif)

Comment: You mean vertical,  nevermind,  I think you mean falls down on y axis without retaining x axis speed. so you want to move it horizontally

Answer (score 2):

You can set velocity directly:

`sprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(10.0,10.0)`

Just set the vx the same as the moving object.

Comment: this works, only now what is the code to determine the speed of a moving object? I can't put a constant value because object1 changes speed and direction.

Comment: If you can set a sprite's velocity, I assume you can get it. Try with moveObject.physicsBody.velocity.x

Comment: seems like its only outputting a velocity when interactive with the physics world. Ive got object1 moving with the SKAction.MoveToY command

Comment: Hmm.... there might be a way to do it not so elegantly. For example, record two x1 and x2 of moving object during two calls of the `update` function. Then divide it by the time interval, to give an estimation of the initial velocity.

Answer (score 0):

use after the remove of the joint

```
object2.physicsBody?.velocity = object1.physicsBody.velocity
object2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

if you use    moveToY
take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522406/skaction-movebyx-not-setting-physicsbody-velocity)

Comment: if Object1 is moving with SKAction.MoveToY, will the physicsBody be able to get the velocity?

Comment: No, as said in the question , MoveToY doesn't go throw the Physics engine, the only way is to calculate it

Comment: If you use moveBy instead of moveTo, then you do not need to calculate anything, you just apply the same moveBy to the child